# How can I work with bitsets in R?

Tags: r, bitset

How can I work with bitsets in R? I googled and found `bit` and `pack` packages but I'm not sure it's what I need. I have big `raw` object that is loaded from DB which is array of bytes. I want to access it as if it was bitset to have following operations

1. count set bits;
2. iterate through set bits in `foreach` loop;
3. set and unset individual bits.

I can probably just convert `raw` to array of bytes (don't know to do that yet btw) and do everything I described using bitwise operators but perhaps some existing package already has that ?

Comment: I edited this to avoid the appearance that you're looking for a package recommendation, which would be off topic.

Comment: *"I googled and found bit and pack packages but I'm not sure it's what I need."* -- Please elaborate on your needs; your question is fairly broad at the moment.

Comment: @nrussell Done.

Comment: Possibly `rawToBits`; e.g. `rawToBits(charToRaw("abcd"))` will give you 32 indexable bits. This may or may not fit your needs.

Comment: @nrussell Yep, that did it. It returned value that looks like array of booleans. How do I check if `x` position is TRUE ?

Comment: @expert Can you add a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `rawToBits` that @nrussell recommended but unfortunately it simply converts raw into vector of booleans with one byte per item. If anyone knows more memory efficient way let me know.